# Handling URLs containing slash '/' character with web.py

Tags: python, url, web.py, slash

I'm coming from Flask and handling URLs with slash character is pretty neat: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/76/

I'm now using web.py and I'd like to do the same. I don't know beforehand how many slashes the url will  have.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use just a normal:

```
urls = (
    "/product/(.*)", product_handler
    )
```

and then product handler takes a single variable:

```
class product_handler:
    def GET(self, url_string):
        url_pieces = url_string.split('/')
        # ...
```

Something like this?